# in this code the hyperlink does not work

Tags: asp.net, html, repeater

The generated hyperlinks in the following code don't work:

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <img src="images/news-icon.jpg" width="14" height="16"
      />&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"
                       Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</marquee>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server"
   SelectMethod="GetFlashNewsTrue" TypeName="NewsServies">
   </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

What's the likely reason for this and how can I debug or fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What are you linking TO? I don't see a target URL on the asp:hyperlink control. Are you setting it in code?

Comment: Maybe you can show a snippet of the rendered HTML?.

Comment: `<marquee>`!! May God have marcy on your soul

Answer (score 2):

you did not set `NavigateUrl` property in your hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl="" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
```